# Why these big checker boxes are seeing in texture and rendered mode?

Tags: rendering

In the render (1st Pic) and texture (2nd Pic) modes, why these big checker boxes are showing? Is there any solution to remove these?
Its a transparent sphere with some noise textures and soft body/collision simulation

Thanks
Arun

[image]

[image]

Comment: Any chance you're using a bevel modifier? Closest I could get to recreating your symptoms came when I attached one to the sphere, but even that doesn't look quite the same. How did you add transparency? Could you post a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: Just now i found a way, I am using "Alpha Blend" in the blend mode and the option  "Show Backface" was ticked. I just unchecked it and the checker boxes vanished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change alpha blending mode to something more accurate like alpha hashed
[image]
[image]